# Angular 2 Performance Optimization for Large List of items

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngrx

Suppose I have a component which displays a list of items

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit{

public list:any;

constructor(private _ls: ListService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
            this._ls.listLoad().subscribe((data) => {
                this.list = data['list'];
            });
    }

    loadMore() {
            this._ls.listLoad(this.page).subscribe((data) => {
                this.list = this.list.concat(data['list']);
                this.page++;
            });
    }

}
```

and in template we have

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of list; let index=index">
    {{ item.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
<a (click)="loadMore()">Load more</a>
```

I want to know that when we click the Load More link and new items are fetched from the server and appended to the list, does the Angular 2 redraw the complete list or just append the new items in the DOM?

If it redraws the complete list, is there any way to just append the newly added items only. Can ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush be helpful in this situation?

In my case I initially display 20 items and each click on load more appends 20 more items to the list. I expect when user load more items few times they may have a list of 1000 to 2000 items in the list. And if the Angular redraws complete list on each append, it may result in performance issue.

Can @ngrx/store give some performance benefit?

Comment: I think if anything @ngrx/store can make this problem worse - at least if you're not careful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*ngFor` should only append the new items while keeping the existing untouched. There is a known issue if you insert new items at the beginning or in the middle which causes items to be remove and re-added instead of just moved.

Comment: Thank you Günter for the clarification, can you please also explain what will happen if a property of an item which is in start of the list is modified. For example its a list of TODOs and the user has loaded 100 items by clicking the Load more link and after that marks third item in the list as Completed, which sets the Completed property of third item in the list as true. Will angular redraw the complete list in this case?

Comment: If you have any experience with @ngrx/store, can you please tell if it could be useful in this specific case?

Comment: I don't know much about @ngrx/store but I don't see how it would be related.

Comment: I was also exploring an option to make list$: Observable<any[]>; setting ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and then using async pipe in template. Should it offer any performance improvements?

Comment: It's not related to rendering, only to change detection. I don't know if `*ngFor` does anyrhing special when the parent component uses `OnPush` os when the `| async` pipe is used, but I guess not`.